# Suppose there are 9 white balls and 3 red balls. A,B,C take turns to pick a ball without replacement . The first person to get a red ball wins.

Tags: probability

Suppose there are 9 white balls and 3 red  balls. A,B,C take turns to pick a ball without replacement . The first person to get a red ball wins.

a) What is the probability that A wins in 1st try?

$\Rightarrow \frac{3}{12}=\frac14$

b) What is the probability that B wins in second try?

$\Rightarrow P(\text{B wins})=P(B \text{ picks a red ball}|\text{A picks a white ball})P(\text{A picks a white ball})=\frac3{11}\frac{9}{12}$
After A has picked a white ball, B has to choose from 3 red balls, among 11 balls remaining

**The above answer should be $\frac14$**

c) What is the probability that B wins in 5th trial?

$ P(\text{B wins in 5th trial})=P(A_1=W,B_1=W,C_1=W,A_2=W,B_2=R)=\frac{9}{12}\frac{8}{11}\frac{7}{10}\frac{6}{9}\frac{3}{8}$

[similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2336591/three-white-and-one-red-ball-probability/2336598#2336598)

Comment: There is a $\frac 14$ chance that $A$ wins on the first try, and a non-zero chance that $A$ wins on a later try, so your answer to $a$ is clearly incorrect.

Comment: @lulu updated..

Comment: Post edit, your answer to $a$ is now correct.  As are your answers to $b$ and $c$.

Comment: I am not so sure about b,c since https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2336591/three-white-and-one-red-ball-probability/2336598#2336598

Comment: That is a different problem.  In that one, there is only one winner and it has an equal probability of being in any slot.  Here there are multiple winners.  for your problem you are looking at very specific paths.